# Retriving xml element's value in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

My xml looks like: myXml.xml

```
<root>
<element1>x,y,z</element1>
<element2>a,b,c</element2>
<element3>p,a,q</element3>
<element4>y,g,h</element4>
</root>
```

I am trying to retrive the value of element with xsl query like:

```
<xsl:variable name="myXml" select="document(myXml.xml)/root"/>
```

and then retrival of say element1 with:

```
<xsl:variable name="element1-val" select="$myXml/local-name()='element1'/@value"/>
```

It is not retruning expected value : x,y,z

Answer (score 1):

You're missing some quotes:

```
<xsl:variable name="myXml" select="document('myXml.xml')/root"/>
```

You need to load the file named `myXml.xml`, whereas your code in the question is attempting to load the file whose name is given by the value of the `<myXml.xml>` child element of the current context node (which doesn't exist, of course).

You're also missing some brackets:

```
<xsl:variable name="element1-val" select="$myXml/*[local-name()='element1']/@value"/>
```

but in fact you don't need the local-name trick at all, just

```
<xsl:variable name="element1-val" select="$myXml/element1/@value"/>
```

would work just fine.